# Show Fltered result in SItecore Form

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have Sitecore form with 5 rows.
Each row have some image and description.
I Have dropdown on top and I want to show/filter rows with images and description based on value selected in dropdown.
So each row should have some tagging to dropdown item and based on value selected in dropdown I need to show results.
How to achieve this is sitecore forms ?